# Putting elements into a sorted list

Tags: java, linked-list

Folks, my method needs to add a new element into already a sorted list, i.e. in a proper position. The point is the method has to add the objects in a diagonal sort. For example,

```
     board.set(1,1,11);
        board.set(2,4,33);
        board.set(3,4,66);
        board.set(3,2,44);
        board.set(3,3,55);
        board.set(1,4,88);
        board.set(0,2,77);
        board.set(0,5,99);
        board.set(2,1,22);
```

The result should be:

```
[(2,1,22), (3,2,44), (1,1,11), (3,3,55), (3,4,66), (0,2,77), (2,4,33), (1,4,88), (0,5,99)]
```

But my program prints this:

```
[(3,4,66), (3,3,55), (3,2,44), (2,4,33), (2,1,22), (1,4,88), (1,1,11), (0,5,99), (0,2,77)]
```

i.e. it does not put the objects into the proper positions.

I have a `LinkedList<RowColElem<T>>leftDiagSeq` where the objects are added and put into a proper position "on the go". What is my code missing?

**NOTE: Im not allowed to use comparators, comparable interface!**

**Code**

```
LinkedList<RowColElem<T>> rowColSeq;
 private void sortedLeftDiagSeq(int row, int col, T x){
      RowColElem<T> object = new RowColElem<T>(row, col, x);
      ListIterator<RowColElem<T>> iter = leftDiagSeq.listIterator();
      RowColElem<T> inListObject;
      boolean added = false;

      while(iter.hasNext()){
           inListObject = iter.next();
           if(object.getRow()-1 < inListObject.getRow() ||
              object.getRow()-1 == inListObject.getRow() &&
              object.getCol()-1 < inListObject.getCol()){
               if( iter.hasPrevious() ){
                   iter.add(object);
               }
           }
      }


  }
```

Comment: If you worry about copy right issues, then probably you shouldn't post the code in the first place or ask in a public forum like SE because the code is still available in the revision.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary criterion is an elements "distance" from the main diagonal, negative distances indicating the lower triangle matrix.

```
if( object.getCol() - object.getRow() < inListObject.getCol() - inListObject.getRow()
    ||
    object.getCol() - object.getRow() == inListObject.getCol() - inListObject.getRow() &&
    object.getCol() < inListObject.getCol()){ ... }
```

I'm not sure about the last term. The data you've provided would also produce the expected result if row numbers are used to break the tie of equal distance from the main diagonal. Probably this doesn't matter since you want order from top-left to bottom-right within one diagonal.

Comment: OMG! I Love you! I've been doing with nested loops which im not allowed to but could not think of anything else. Thank you so much! @laune.... Btw how long have you been in programming? It seems you picked my problem very easily when I've been doing this problem for hours!

Comment: I guess this is more a matter of experience with dealing with matrices in mathematics where you learn about index expressions for the elements in certain "places". That was a long time ago but it seems that we had to learn it well...